# Inspect Element in Safari?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

I've tried Firebug Lite for Safari, but content wasn't editable. Is there an alternative to edit HTML, CSS, etc?

Answer (score 58):

Just enable **Show Developer Menu** in Safari's Preferences, *Advanced* tab.

[image: Enable-Develop-mode-Safari]

It will enable the option *Inspect Element* when you right click the page. You can also start it with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

You can get more info about this option in [Safari for Developers - Tools](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) and [Safari Web Inspector Guide: The Develop Menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/TheDevelopMenu/TheDevelopMenu.html).

Comment: Yeah, but if I want to see the computed style of a web link, hovering doesn't update the style and clicking the link on the page goes to the link target. How can I show the computed style of a link without Safari instead jumping to the link target?

Comment: @clearlight you can use `Computed` tab: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari-developer/view-the-computed-css-dev56fdc8177/mac

Answer (score 0):

You can edit css by double clicking on the "{" symbol present in the right side css section. Also you can edit the html by removing the firebug plugin and then doing inspect element mode.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with simple steps

in menu bar click on **Edit->preference->advance**
at bottom click the check box true that is for **Show develop menu in menu bar**
now a develop menu is display at menu bar where you can see all develop option and inspect.[image]

Comment: Does not work on current version